# how to send message in Team channel via Daemon application

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to send message to Team channel without a user from an external app via HTTP call . So for this I have created app as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview)

Now I have written JAVA code to send message as suggested here: [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) 
But it seems that it is not possible to send message via HTTP call because of the permission Type Application is not supported. I am getting 401

```
     URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/<tanentid>/channels/<channelid>/messages");

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("content", "Hello world");
JSONObject mainobj = new JSONObject();
mainobj.put("body", obj);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
String postBody = mainobj.toString();
conn.getOutputStream().write(postBody.getBytes());

int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
if(httpResponseCode == 200) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    StringBuilder response;
    try{
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
    return response.toString();
} else {
    return String.format("Connection returned HTTP code: %s with message: %s",
            httpResponseCode, conn.getResponseMessage());
}
```

This HTTP call work fine :  `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels`

1) Is it possible somehow? 
2) If not then [Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams) can send message based on input from external App via HTTP call?

Comment: Web-hooks are used to post messages to teams channel. Could you please try Webhook sample as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook)

Comment: Thanks, the problem with webhook is that post messages does not need any access token which is a security issue from my point of view.

Comment: Could you please try to send proactive message as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#creating-a-channel-conversation)? Also Could you please try [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/NotifyController.cs#L19) sample?